# Install Sql Server Express Conditionally during Window Application setup process

Tags: installation, sql-server-express

I have 2 queries..

1. Can I include one of my own interfaces, not the custom dialog the setup project provides, in the setup project? The interface will help user to choose an option for installing Sql Server Express during setup or not.
2. If the user select to install it, what are the steps do I need to follow

Answer (score 0):

See [Embedding SQL Server Express into Custom Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Run setup.exe of Express with a Templete.ini parameter, from within your application installer. This ini file is easily created by first running the installer of Express separately, but cancel at the last step. That step mentions the location and name of the ini file.